# Prevent UIScrollView in UIAlertView with four buttons

Tags: ios6, uiscrollview, uialertview

I am using a UIAlertView with four option buttons. This has however caused the message to be put into a UIScrollView. How can I prevent this?

I know one should have fewer buttons, but iCloud offers too many options. The buttons are essential: remove local data and use icloud data, replace icloud data with local data, merge local data with icloud data and cancel.

Btw: it is an iPad only app - so there is enough screen real estate for a few lines of UIAlertView goodness

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended solution is to use `UIActionSheet` instead.